# How to retrieve data from two column in SQL with same primary id but do not repeat the same data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and a unique id.

**table tom**

| id | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Two | Three |
| 2 | four | five |
| 3 | six | seven |

**table jerry**

| id | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | def |
| 2 | hij | klm |
| 2 | nop | qrs |
| 2 | tuv | wxy |
| 3 | zab | cde |
| 3 | fgh | ijk |

my query is

```
select t.col2, t.col3, j.col4, j.col5 
from tom t
inner join jerry j on j.id = t.id 
where t.id = 2 GROUP BY t.id.
```

Desired Output

| id | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | four | five | hij,nop,tuv | klm,qrs,wxy |

but i get three lines as deffrent lines for each data.

please help me out.
Note* correct the question if its wrong.

Comment: What do you mean "do not repeat the same data"?

Comment: yes, I don't want to repeat all the data. I was wondering if we can display called data in the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `group_concat()`:

```
select t.id, t.col2, t.col3,
       group_concat(j.col4), group_concat(j.col5)
from tom t inner join
     jerry j
     on j.id = t.id 
where t.id = 2 
group by t.id, t.col2, t.col3;
```

The query in your question has two big errors.  The lesser is the `o.id` is not defined.  I assume you really intend `t.id`.

More importantly, the `SELECT` columns and `GROUP BY` columns are inconsistent.  You query is malformed and should return an error -- but older versions of MySQL do allow that syntax.

Comment: Your answer worked. Thank You
yes, I am using Mysql 5.3.